# Как запустить meteor в режиме отладки?

Tags: meteor

Запускаю так

```
meteor debug


W20180909-12:13:05.082(3)? (STDERR) Debugger listening on [::]:5959
W20180909-12:13:07.380(3)? (STDERR) Debugger listening on [::]:5959
W20180909-12:13:07.758(3)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20180909-12:13:07.758(3)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20180909-12:13:07.758(3)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20180909-12:13:07.759(3)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20180909-12:13:07.759(3)? (STDERR) 
W20180909-12:13:07.759(3)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20180909-12:13:07.759(3)? (STDERR) 
W20180909-12:13:07.759(3)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
```

А дальше как начать отладку?  Вот это что значит?

```
Debugger listening on [::]:5959
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно перейти по адресу `localhost:5959` или `127.0.0.1:5959` там будет отладчик как в хроме.

Comment: Перехожу, но пишет страница недоступна. Отладчика нигде нет. 
Версия node js 10.10.0 
Meteor 1.4.3.2